# Using nth-child to make a chess pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

I am breaking my head to achieve something quite relatively simple here.

I need to select every 3rd and 4th element on my page, how could I do that using css :nth-child()?

JS answers also welcome.

Thanks a lot.

***EDIT

Apologies guys my question was badly written. 
I attached an example below of what I need.

This is the outcome I need,
http://jsfiddle.net/8FXL6/

```
        <li></li>
        <li class="highlight"></li>
        <li class="highlight"></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        etc
```

Without hardcoding the class names.

Comment: Please add some example markup, and what you expect to be found.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
*:nth-child(3),*:nth-child(4){
}
```

Technically, this selects every element that is the 3rd or 4th child in its container. If you want to select *every* 3rd or 4th element (3,4,6,8 etc.), use:

```
*:nth-child(3n),*:nth-child(4n){
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AY3jq/)

From your edit, you need:

```
li:nth-child(4n-2),li:nth-child(4n-1){
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8FXL6/1/)

Comment: Thanks for commenting. have a look at my edit above, there's a jsfiddle exmaple.
your code doesnt work how i need it to :(

Comment: @peduarte You have extra parenthesis in css that's why it's not working - http://jsfiddle.net/8FXL6/4/

Comment: @peduarte I've already made a fiddle for you. Click the second `DEMO` link.

Comment: My bad. This is perfect. Very clever. +1

Answer (score 4):

You can use comma to combine selectors using [**nth-child**](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) to get elements,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8FXL6/2/)**

```
elements = $('div .className :nth-child(3), div .className :nth-child(4)');
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting. have a look at my edit above, there's a jsfiddle exmaple.

Comment: Thanks, but that only selects the 2nd and 3rd. it needs to carry on... eg. http://jsfiddle.net/8FXL6/

Answer (score 1):

How about using css only?

Every third element:

```
*:nth-child(3n+3) {color: red}
```

Every fourth element:

```
*:nth-child(4n+4) {color: blue}
```

Here's demo on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dufsx/

Comment: Thanks for commenting. have a look at my edit above, there's a jsfiddle exmaple.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using CSS only

```
 *:nth-child(4n+2){background:blue;color: white;}
 *:nth-child(4n+3){background:blue;color: white;}
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KZAzU/1/)